How to Pass Extra Data to Callback Functions in Python C API?
I'm working on integrating C code with Python using the Python C API, and I need to register callback functions with additional data. Specifically, I want to pass extra data to my callback function so that it can be accessed when the callback is invoked.
Here is a simplified version of my problem:
I need to register some functions in the Python interpreter using the Python C API. My callback function is supposed to have the following signature:
PyObject* callback(PyObject* self, PyObject* args);


However, I also need to pass some extra data to this callback. For example, in the Tcl library, there is a function Tcl_CreateCommand that allows passing additional client data like this (https://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tcl8.0a1/CrtCommand.3.html):
Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, command_name, callback, client_data);


In my case, I want to achieve similar functionality with the Python C API. How can I pass additional data to a callback function in Python C API?
Here's what I have so far:
#include <Python.h>

// Define a structure to hold additional data
typedef struct {
    int some_value;
} CallbackData;

// Define the callback function
PyObject* callback(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    // Retrieve and use the additional data here
    // ...
}

// Function to register the callback
void register_callback(PyObject* module) {
    // Setup additional data
    CallbackData* data = (CallbackData*)malloc(sizeof(CallbackData));
    data->some_value = 42;
    // Where to pass the data to access it from callback?
    PyMethodDef* foo_def = new PyMethodDef{"foo", callback, METH_VARARGS, "Docs"}
    PyObject* foo = PyCFunction_New(foo_def, NULL);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "foo", foo);
}


How can I modify this code to ensure that the callback function can access the extra data (CallbackData in this case) when it is invoked?
Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Show the registration code.


in the Tcl library, there is a function Tcl_CreateCommand that allows passing additional client data

Sort of.  A custom Tcl command automatically has access to a pointer to the Tcl interpreter that is running it, and to a pointer to a client data object that provides a data context for executing the command.  Importantly, the client data is its own thing, not accounted among the arguments to the command.  It's almost as if every custom Tcl command is a closure.

I want to achieve similar functionality with the Python C API. How can I pass additional data to a callback function in Python C API?

Python does not have an explicit concept of such a "client data" context.  Neither in pure Python nor in the C API.  It does have closures, but those are based on the context in which a particular function is defined, and yours is defined altogether outside Python proper.  Among your options are:

The function will be able to access its module's variables via the modules's namespace dictionary, so you could put the wanted context data in such a variable (as a Python object).  This allows you to substitute a different object at runtime, from Python.

The extension module can set up the data during module initialization, and store it (or a pointer to it) in a static variable defined in the module's C source.  The C function can then access it from there, via normal C mechanisms.  In this case, if you want to be able to replace or modify the client data from Python then you'll need to create extra functions for that purpose.

The function can be totally normal, accepting the client data as an ordinary positional or named parameter.  You could then define the client data entirely on the Python side, and wrap the native function calls in an ordinary Python closure that provides the client data to the function, transparently to callers (of the closure).


